# Get list of available WiFi spots

Tags: android, list, wifi

I'm creating an app that needs internet connection. So when the WiFi setting is not enabled, I pop up a message to switch it on. But when it's on, it's not nessecarily connected to a WiFi Access Point.

Is there any way to show all current available WiFi spots in a list?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look on the methods of the [`WifiManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) class. Especially the `getScanResults()` method will return the results of the last scan for Wifi networks. Be aware that the `getConfiguredNetworks()` only returns those networks that have been configured beforehand by the user (i.e. the password has been provided for a secured network, etc).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Will do you also know when the device scans again?
I'm also doubting to either show a pop-up list with the available connections and then I want to connect to the selected one, if that's possible or just show the Wireless settings screen.

Comment: You can issue a scan by using `startScan()` command and register a receiver for the events it is firing (see documentation). But, I would simply start the Wireless settings screen to let the user select a Wifi network. This way, the user can simply use the UI he is used to use in such cases.

Comment: I've tested WifiManager, startScan() and getScanResults successfully, but due to an explosion of extra data I'm going to go with the Wireless Settings Screen. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Can I ask another issue, it's a bit off-topic. So I start the Wireless Settings Screen, connect to a WiFi spot and hit back. Normally the Activity goes in the `onResume` method, where I load my Tweets again. But only, he won't load them. This `onresume` method works for every other Activity I start.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about that. Maybe it's the best to start a complete new question for that issue.

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#startScan()