# Android: Fetching list of available WiFi connection details

Tags: android, wifi

Need to fetch list of available wifi connection details?

can any one know. Please help.

Comment: You can find the solution from the links below.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452940/how-can-i-get-android-wifi-scan-results-into-a-list

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936191/get-list-of-available-wifi-spots

Comment: please search all posts which are related to your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use this to scan available wifi

```
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Test_allActivity extends Activity {

TextView mainText;
WifiManager mainWifi;
WifiReceiver receiverWifi;
List<ScanResult> wifiList;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainText);
  mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
  receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
  registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(
  WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
  mainWifi.startScan();
  mainText.setText("\nStarting Scan...\n");
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Refresh");
 return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);}
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
  mainWifi.startScan();
  mainText.setText("Starting Scan");
  return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);}
 protected void onPause() {
   unregisterReceiver(receiverWifi);
   super.onPause();
 }
/*
protected void onResume() {
    registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(
    WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
   super.onResume();
}*/

class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
  sb = new StringBuilder();
  wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
  for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++){
     sb.append(new Integer(i+1).toString() + ".");
     sb.append((wifiList.get(i)).toString());
     sb.append("\n");
}
mainText.setText(sb);
}
  }}
```

Give This Permissions in **androidmanifest.xml** file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Thanks its works fine. I need to split into inividual string and to store in a separate edittext for individual selection