# how to show list of available wifi in android application for API 8?

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-networking

I'm working on an android application that should search available wifi and connect to the chosen network. first of all I want to show all wifi networks in my app. I found some tutorial but all of theme need API 14 and I have to use API 8 for this approach.
Any idea would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you MUST have API 14 as a `minSdkVersion`. There simply is not such a function in earlier API(s), thats why Google added it.

Change the `minSdkVersion` under your `AndroidManifest.xml` to show `android:minSdkVersion="14"`

Comment: thank you for quick response. I found couple of tutorial about API 14 but can't help. do you know any helpful source? thanks

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936191/get-list-of-available-wifi-spots